# Dynamic query using like operator

Tags: soql, query, dynamic-soql

What's wrong in this query?
It's throwing below error message

> Compile Error: Found punction symbol or operator '%' that isn't valid
>   in Apex

```
String QueryString= 'SELECT id,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone From Contact Where FirstName Like \ '%' + text + '%\' ';     

 conList = Database.query(QueryString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its was just space issue between escape character in your query

```
String QueryString= 'SELECT id,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone From Contact Where FirstName Like \'%' + text + '%\'';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get compile-time checking and automatic [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) protection for this case using this technique:

```
String likeText = '%' + text + '%';
Contact[] contacts = [
        Select id,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone
        From Contact
        Where FirstName Like :likeText
        ];
```